# How to customise the string representation of an object while debugging Python in VS Code

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a pretty complex python script I'm working on in VS Code, and I've realised that my life would be a lot easier if the classes I'm using were represented in meaningful ways.

Currently, the debug panel represents my objects as things like `<foo.Bar object at 0x000002C643F960A0>`, but I'd much rather that I could specify how they should be presented, by overriding some function of it.

I've tried overriding the `__str__()` function to no avail. My googling sadly hasn't come up with anything useful.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Apologies if this is a repost - the similar questions thing isn't scrolling properly.

Comment: try overriding both `__str__(self)` and `__repr__(self)`.

Comment: Please show how you are overriding `__str__` and how you are trying to print the objects. It's highly likely that you messed up something on the `__str__` method

Comment: Overriding `__repr__(self)` works!!! I didn't realise it was a function that exists

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done by overriding the `__repr__()` method of the object.

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name: str, age: int) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Person({self.name=}, {self.age=})"
```

The `__repr__()` method is used by VS Code's debugger rather than the `__str__()` method, since `__str__()` is intended for user-facing representation and `__repr__()` is intended for debugging.